# Usage pointers and memcpy in c

Tags: c

In [this article](https://web.archive.org/web/20071031100114/http://www.brucemo.com/compchess/programming/pv.htm) the author provides some example code, written in C. I am not experienced in the language, so I thought I could ask you guys if my understanding of the provided code is correct or not.

I understand the main purpose of the function: it is just an implementation of the NegaMax search with AlphaBeta pruning (and keeping track of the PV, as explained in the article). My main problem is here:

```
pline->argmove[0] = ThisMove();

memcpy(pline->argmove + 1, line.argmove, line.cmove * sizeof(MOVE));

pline->cmove = line.cmove + 1;
```

My current understanding: each iteration of the `while` loop, if the current move being evaluated is better than the best move found so far, the current move is stored at the first index of the `Move[]` `pline.argmove`. All subsequent legal moves of the current one are then stored in the remaining array indicies. At the end of the method, the `pline.argmove` should now contain all subsequent moves of the best move found, along with the best move itself.

Is my understanding of the code in the article correct?

Complete code:

```
typedef struct tagLINE {
    int cmove;              // Number of moves in the line.
    MOVE argmove[moveMAX];  // The line.
} LINE;

int AlphaBeta(int depth, int alpha, int beta, LINE *pline)
{
    LINE line;

    if (depth == 0) {
        pline->cmove = 0;
        return Evaluate();
    }
    GenerateLegalMoves();
    while (MovesLeft()) {
        MakeNextMove();
        val = -AlphaBeta(depth - 1, -beta, -alpha, &line);
        UnmakeMove();
        if (val >= beta)
            return beta;
        if (val > alpha) {
            alpha = val;

            pline->argmove[0] = ThisMove();

            memcpy(pline->argmove + 1, line.argmove,
                   line.cmove * sizeof(MOVE));

            pline->cmove = line.cmove + 1;
        }
    }
    return alpha;
}
```

Comment: There is no "C"/"C++" code it is either one or the other. I guess its "C" because memcpy is being used. (should have been std::copy in C++).

Comment: There is no `while` loop in the posted code.

Comment: Use the title to explain your *technical problem*, not that you're having a problem.

Comment: @WilliamPursell The complete code is in the article

Comment: I don't see a question anywhere here. You post a tiny out-of-context code snippet and then summarize your understanding of what it does. Great. What's your "main problem"?

Comment: @NathanPierson read the first paragraph again

Comment: @NathanPierson I edited my post to inlude a direct question now, not an indirect one.

Comment: We don't generally answer questions about external resources.  SO questions should be self-contained.  All code relevant to the question should be included in the question itself.  And if that makes it too long, then your question is probably too broad.

Comment: @i486 I know memcpy will still work (even today with or without std::). But std::copy is the typesafe variant (and can actually be faster)

Answer (score 2):

> Is my understanding of the code in the article correct?

> My current understanding: Each iteration of the while loop, if the current move being evaluated is better than the best move found so far,

That seems to suppose that "better" equates to "the recursive call to `AlphaBeta()` returns the lowest value."  That's consistent with the negamax approach, but not necessarily a given -- it depends on the behavior of `Evaluate()`.

> the current move is stored at the first index of the `Move[] pline.argmove`.

More or less.  Whatever `ThisMove()` returns is stored in the first (index 0) element of `pline->argmove`, which is an array of `Move` objects.  There is no such thing as `pline.argmove`.

> All subsequent legal moves of the current one are then stored in the remaining array indecies.

It doesn't look like "all subsequent legal moves" is a good characterization.  Supposing that this is indeed a correctly-functioning negamax implementation, it is the up to `depth` *optimal* moves following the current one, that will be copied into `pline->argmove`, at contiguous positions starting from index 1.

> At the end of the method, the pline.argmove should now contain all subsequent moves of the best move found, along with the best move itself.

Again, there is no `pline.argmove`.  And C does not have "methods".

But just before the *function* returns, `pline->argmove` will contain the `pline->cmove` moves of the best sequence discovered by searching ahead the specified number of moves, provided that any acceptable sequence at all was discovered.  Note in particular that the function's search may be terminated before all possible moves have been evaluated (when `val >= beta`), which may be before *any* move sequence is copied into `pline->argmove`.

Comment: Thanks, excuse me for my bad C-terminology ;)

Comment: This is a good explanation. Worth emphasizing that every recursion produces another `line`, which will only get bumped to the previous level of recursion if `val > alpha`.